# How to round off H-axis label values to integers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have a google visualisation linechart. I am having issues formatting the labels on the h-axis. I would like to have them rounded off to integers so it looks neater. I have looked at the documentation but could not find a solution. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="myChart2" name="myChart2" width="500" height="280"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'SPS');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'WGT');
  var chartdatax = ["47", "47", "38", "35", "35"];
  var chartdatay = ["1500", "2300", "2300", "1950", "1500"];
  for (var i = 0; i < chartdatax.length; i++) {
    chartData.addRow([parseFloat(chartdatax[i]), parseFloat(chartdatay[i])]);
  };
  options2 = {
    height: 500,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'SPS',
      gridlines: {
        count: 15
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'WGT',
      gridlines: {
        count: 15
      }
    },
    chartArea: {
      top: 40,
      width: "70%",
      height: "75%"
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    pointSize: 5
  };
  myLineChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('myChart2'));
  myLineChart.draw(chartData, options2);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/w83mdx3y/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `format:'#,###'` to your `hAxis` object:

```
hAxis: {
  format:'#,###',
  title: 'SPS',
  gridlines: {
    count: 15
  }
},
```

Here's an updated version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w83mdx3y/3/

See [customizing axes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#number-formats) in the charts documentation for more information on how this works.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro. It however creates duplicate label values when I change the values of the array. https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/w83mdx3y/4/

Comment: Can you give me an example with the values changing? Do you call `myLineChart.draw(chartData, options2);` again?

Comment: No, I mean there are duplicate label values like `38, 38`. By changing values I meant I changed `var chartdatax = ["47", "47", "38", "35", "35"];` to `var chartdatax = ["47", "47.1", "38.5", "35", "35"];`. You can see the result in the above fiddle.

Comment: Do you require 15 gridlines? If you remove that element from `hAxis`, it just uses whole numbers:
https://jsfiddle.net/w83mdx3y/5/

Comment: Ah! I don't require the 15 gridlines. That should solve the issue combined with setting the format! Thank you so much Alessandro!